# The order of charts by month of facet (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have prepared a chart for two months: December 2023 and January 2024.

I prepare the division (facet) into months and I get January on the left and December on the right.

```
ggplot (Energy.day %>% filter (Date >= as.Date("2023-12-01") & Date <= as.Date("2024-01-31")))+
  geom_col (aes (x = Day_Month, y = Energy), fill = "green3", size = 0.5) +
  scale_x_date (breaks = "3 day",
                date_labels = format ("%d")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "none",
        legend.justification = "center") +
  labs (x = "", y = "Energy [kWh]", fill = "") +
  facet_wrap(~Msc)
```

The natural expectation is that the order will be reverse. How to do it?

Comment: Sounds like `Msc` is ordered differently than you want. Maybe it is a number of the month (1 < 12), or you are using some sort of text format/language where the Jan one is alphabetically earlier than the Dec one, or you have a factor that is not ordered the way you intend. The answer is typically to make `Msc` a factor that is ordered the way you want. I like the `forcats` package for this.

Comment: It will be easier to help if you can provide some sample data. That makes it easier for us to test potential solutions, and reduces ambiguity e.g. about what type of data your `Msc` is.

Comment: ```Msc``` is a number from 1 to 12

Comment: So `Msc` is an integer ranging from 1 to 12, and when you facet by this number you are expecting that `12` should come before `1`? The order of facets is _never_ determined by the arrangement of the data, it is _always_ determine by the natural sort of the variable. In this case, if it is integer, then they sort like numbers, meaning from 1-12 instead of 12, 1, ..., 11. If you want them to be sorted date-wise, then you need to use a date-like object in your call to `facet_wrap` or you need to convert `Msc` to a factor and control the levels yourself.

Comment: I don't expect it. The result is completely logical. However, I need to change the order. Replacing the month with the year and month will probably be effective. However, I don't know how to prepare such a factor. It will be visible in the chart header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare with and without the 2nd line below:

```
data.frame(Msc = 1:12) |>
  mutate(Msc = factor(Msc) |> forcats::fct_shift(n = 6)) |>
  ggplot() +
  facet_wrap(~Msc)
```

There are a variety of convenience functions in `forcats` for rearranging factors, making them in order of appearance, or some other variable, or swapping them, etc. `fct_shift` can be helpful for time series (fiscal years, water years, weekdays, etc.) where you want to keep the factors in order, but shift the start point of the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for `forcats::fct_relevel`. You can reorder the levels in the order you prefer (provided you capture all values of `Msc`). Keeping the format of your code above, the following should work:

```
ggplot(Energy.day %>% 
      filter(Date >= as.Date("2023-12-01") & Date <= as.Date("2024-01-31")) %>% 
      mutate(Msc = forcats::fct_relevel(Msc, c("December","January")))
   ) +
geom_col(aes(x = Day_Month, y = Energy), fill = "green3", size = 0.5) +
scale_x_date(breaks = "3 day", date_labels = format ("%d")) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5),
      legend.position = "none",
      legend.justification = "center") +
labs(x = "", y = "Energy [kWh]", fill = "") +
facet_wrap(~Msc)
```